# Is it possible to write/save data/variables in Memory instead of the sdcard to extend the lifetime?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, internet, memory, file

I tried looking for a similar question but had no luck.

**The goal is to extend the sdcard's lifetime by saving data to RAM instead of the card.**

The program in question is running every *30mins to n-hours* (not sure yet) and will fetch data from a webpage the internet (**web crawling**) and save it locally to compare with the next fetch cycle if the data changed.

**So my goal is to "save" in Memory instead of the sdcard.**

An idea I have from to top of my head is to save with WriteMemoryProcess or some other C, x86 Assembler register etc.. trickery.

Actually, is this even worth it? I installed Log2RAM but I don't know if something like this would make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [*'wearout mechanism'*](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=wearout+mechanism+SD+card) in all SD cards. It follows that the less you write to any given SD card, the longer it will last. I think it's reasonable to be concerned about failures regardless of whether or not you've experienced them. [@Milliways' makes a sound point in his answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/133064/83790) regarding longevity and costs, but these are judgments which will vary depending upon use-case and individual preference.

Wrt your *headline question*, the answer is **"Yes, it is possible to write/save data/variables to memory instead of the SD card."** Perhaps the simplest way is to write your saved webpage data in `/tmp`; e.g. `/tmp/webpagedata/somefilename`.

`/tmp` uses the `tmpfs` file system, and in most modern Linux systems (including RPi OS), `/tmp` is automatically mounted as a `tmpfs` by `systemd`. Which means that you needn't bother with creating an entry for it in `/etc/fstab` - you simply boot, and use it. Write to it in exactly the same way you would write to a file on your SD card.

But, depending on your use-case, there may be [*a catch*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+catch)<sup>(see #13)</sup>: Everything you write to `/tmp` will be lost in a reboot. Consequently, depending on your requirements, you may or may not need to take measures to avoid data loss. And therein lies [*the rub*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20rub) - if you can't afford to lose any data, you must backup `/tmp` to non-volatile media.

Comment: "* if you can't afford to lose any data, you must backup `/tmp` to non-volatile media*". If you can't afford to lose data, don't save it to `/tmp`...

Answer (score 2):

Similar questions are asked often, usually by people who have no actual experience of failure.

There are means of minimising writes, but in 9 years with multiple Pi several running 24/7 I have only 2 failures. SD Cards are so cheap they should be considered expendable and reliable brands last years.

My original Pi Model B is still running, although it is only pulled out occasionally. My Pi Model B+ running Stretch has been logging data continuously since January 2019.

On the other hand I have a dozen HDD which have failed.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the n interval writes to the sdcard (in a file) are acceptable/not worth thinking about memory & sdcard lifespan etc...?